# RLink with R3.5.0 on Windows 10 and Mathematica 10.2 is not working

Tags: rlink

If I install R with

```
InstallR["RHomeLocation" -> "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.0"]
```

the system (Mathematica 10.2 on Windows 10 Pro and R-3.5.0) is giving the following message:

> Error R.DLL version does not match (DLL 3.5.0, expecting 3.1.1

Regards